# Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/provider_paths')

Tags: android, google-api, android-fileprovider

I was developing an app for google service text detection, and encounter a problem for sharing files using File_PROVIDER.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="myPackageFoo">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/API_KEY" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="myPackageFoo.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

For res/xml/provider_paths.xml:

```
<paths>
<files-path path="images/" name="myimages" />
<external-path name="download" path="download/"/>
</paths>
```

However I always get this compilation error:

Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/provider_paths').

What went wrong?

Comment: When did this error came? at the time of build or at runtime when you getting Uri from FileProvider?

Comment: at the time of build

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just spent ages on the same issue. 
Some people suggested typos (no typos there) some mentioned other possibilities like wrong folder or advising techniques of modifying config.xml or checking sdk versions....
The thing that was missing for me was that the "provider_paths.xml" Build Action was set to Content and not to AndroidResource hence it was never copied during compilation hence it was missing and never found...
I think this is the same issue here.

Comment: From where I can  change this provider path?

Comment: You would need to either edit project file manually or do it via Visual Studio (or any other code editor). If you choose the latter, go to the Solution Explorer, select provider_paths.txt file, right-click to reveal the context menu, select "Properties" and in the Properties window in the "Build Action" row select "AndroidResource". That should do the trick :)

Comment: Also check that the xml files are valid.